# MoveIt collision checking: when is contact stored vs. not stored

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(ROS version is Melodic)

I'm using `PlanningScene::checkCollision()` to check for collisions, and noticed that when there are multiple collisions -- as in more than 1 pair of colliding objects -- not all contacts are stored in `CollisionResult.contacts` ([struct reference](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/moveit_core/html/structcollision__detection_1_1CollisionResult.html)).

I see log messages like (note the `not stored` in the *third* log message):

```
Found 1 contacts between 'object_0' (type 'Object') and 'link_1' (type 'Robot link'), which constitute a collision. 1 contacts will be stored

Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 1 contacts are stored)

Found a contact between 'object_5' (type 'Object') and 'link_7' (type 'Robot link'), which constitutes a collision. Contact information is not stored.

Collision checking is considered complete (collision was found and 1 contacts are stored)
```

---

**What actually determines which contacts get stored and which ones don't?**

---

When I unpack `CollisionResult.contacts`, it only has information on the contact that was stored and is missing the one that wasn't stored (which is in agreement with the logs). `checkCollision()` has a [few overloads](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html) and the one I call is:

```
PlanningScene::checkCollision(const collision_detection::CollisionRequest& req, collision_detection::CollisionResult& res, const robot_state::RobotState& robot_state)
```

`CollisionRequest`'s `contacts`, `distance`, `cost`, and `verbose` are all set to `true`.

For my use-case I need all contacts because I'm reasoning a bunch of stuff off of that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389188/moveit-collision-checking:-when-is-contact-stored-vs.-not-stored/) by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2021-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

([Posted this on MoveIt discord](https://discord.com/channels/717058325480734830/717148778238574623/902755753805381682) where I got the answer. Turned out to be a case of RTFM)

`CollisionRequest` ([struct reference](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/moveit_core/html/structcollision__detection_1_1CollisionRequest.html)) has a field `max_contacts` -- *Overall maximum number of contacts to compute* -- whose default value is 1 ([constructor list](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/moveit_core/html/include_2moveit_2collision__detection_2collision__common_8h_source.html#l00174)).

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2021-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0